# Connecting PHP TO MYSQL ERROR message

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

When connecting to localhost with this code, I get an error message. I'm unable to connect to MYSQL and I'm not sure why:

```
    <?php

//connect
$link = mysqli_connect("$localhost", "$root", "$password", "$database");
if (!$link)
{



    $output = 'Unable to connect to the database server.';
    include 'output.html.php';
    exit();
}

if (!mysqli_set_charset($link, 'utf8'))

    $output = 'Unable to set database connection encoding.';
    include 'output.html.php';
    exit();
}
if (!mysqli_select_db($link, '$database'))
{
    $output = 'Unable to locate the Teamster database.';
    include 'output.html.php';
    exit();
}
$output = 'Database connection established. ';
include 'output.html.php';
?>
```

I get this error message. This is what populates when I refresh the page, above a form that I've created. Is this a problem of connectivity or coding?

```
//check connection //if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)) // { echo "Failed to connect to        MySQL: " . mysql_connect_error(); // } //
```

Comment: I think you're missing `<?php` at the beginning of `output.html.php`, so it's displaying the PHP instead of executing it.

Comment: That connection command is implemented pretty "weired": `"localhost"` or `$localhost` but certainly not `"$localhost"`...

Comment: can you post the code to `output.html.php`?

Comment: Can you post what is in the variables $localhost, $root, $password, $database

Comment: Barmar you were correct. I fixed the php tag and got this: Database connection established.

//check connection //if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)) // { echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_connect_error(); // } //?>

Comment: Riggsfolly I just used those as variables. I put in "localhost", "root", "mypassword", "mydatabasename";

Comment: As a side, why are you mixing `mysqli_connect_errno` with `mysql_connect_error`? - ie. `if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)) // { echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_connect_error();`. the `mysql_connect_error()` would not give you anything as you are using `mysqli_connect()`

Comment: @arkascha: nothing wrong with `"$localhost"`. it's cargo cult programming, but evaluates to pretty much the same thing either way.

Comment: @MarcB: .....and I just learned a new term: "cargo cult programming" :-)

Comment: @RocketHazmat: you tend to see a LOT of it here.

Comment: @MarcB: Yeah >.<  At least there's a cool name for it :-D

Comment: Oops @Sean I forgot to reply to your question. (mysqli_connect_errno($con)) is actually commented out because I found the above code to be more thorough. You're right I think that is very redundant.

Comment: It is not that it is redundant, the issue is you are mixing `mysqli_*` with `mysql_*`. If you were to use that code when `if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))` returns true you will get no (or incorrect) error message because you are then echoing `mysql_connect_error()` which would not give you the error message from `mysqli_connect_errno($con)`. That would be like doing `if($a=blue) echo $b` and then wondering why you are not getting `blue`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are getting: 
//check connection //if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)) // { echo "Failed to connect to        MySQL: " . mysql_connect_error(); // } //

then this is your problem:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("$localhost", "$root", "$password", "$database");
```

where loclhost, username, password, database combination is not correct.
also make sure you are on the right port and that you are allowed to connect with those credential.

A "cannot connect to db" is always due to some combination of that line and not because of code since you failed on `if (!$link)`

Comment: I've trippled checked all these variables and they appear to be correct. I'm using the default 3306 port, but who can I be sure I'm able to connect with those credentials? I can connect with Workbench just fine with them so far..Any other ideas? Thanks again btw.

Comment: hard code that line with your credential - and see if it connect - if it does then you probably did something also as someone mentioned if localhost is being used you do not need to $localhost

Comment: Thanks for your input also azngunit81. I've realized that I was forgetting to put mysqli_select_db(); with its parameters to select my DB. Now the only message i'm getting is "Unable to select DB". Any ideas all? I'm sure thats the only parameter not working because i checked every other one.

Comment: are you reselecting the same db or another one? if its another one make sure the credential that you are using are applicable to that DB. Ie: user1 has access to db1 but not db2 ...

Answer (score 0):

I (don't think I can) post comments, but it would help if you posted the exact error message.

eg the output of

```
mysql_connect_error()
```

From what I can tell though, you should make sure that the $localhost is set to something (probably "localhost", and that you're using the correct username and password.

Answer (score 0):

never output a fixed error message, when the system could TELL you what's wrong:

```
$output = 'Unable to connect to the database server:' . mysqli_connect_error();
```

Comment: Is this meant to be an answer?

Comment: @Marc B should I delete that output message and add "mysqli_connect_error();" ?

Comment: no, the text of the message is fine. just don't ignore what mysql could be telling you about the problem. e.g. "something wrong wrong: here's what it is" is by far more useful than just "something went wrong".

Comment: @MarcB great point. What do you think about this error message: Database connection established.

//check connection //if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)) // { echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_connect_error(); // } //?>